# Javascript alert not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new at using MVC 4 and Javascript. I created a javascript that does not send the alert when the page is ready. I cant seem to figure out what i am doing wrong.

my code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Import";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(this).ready(function () {
        alert("test");
    });

</script>
<h2>Import</h2>
<form id="form1">
    @Html.DropDownList("TableDDL")
</form>
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: This should work, as `$(this)` would point to the `window` object. Do you have a reference to the jquery.js file? See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E2A9N/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        alert("test");
    });
</script>
```

**Note:** Make sure you have included reference of jQuery Library on your page.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass in `document`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

which is equivalent to:

```
$(function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you included the jQuery correctly?

```
$(this).ready(function () {
        alert("test");
});
```

This code should work.
 Check http://jsfiddle.net/yM5PC/

Comment: I didn't declare the src in my code. instead i did it in the layout shared cshtml file. But KPL's soloution works

Comment: Strange, it should work if you included the correct layout on your page (maybe you have multiple Shared/_Layouts). Anyway if its working like this, then perfect :)